# Restore more than two files .bak using 1 script or query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, backup, restore

I have more backup files (`.bak`) and I want restore all of them in one script in SQL Server 2012. So, is there any script for doing this action?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can use [sp_RestoreGene](https://paulbrewer.wordpress.com/sp_restoregene/)

> This procedure queries msdb database backup history and database file
>   details in master. It builds and returns RESTORE DATABASE commands as
>   it's result set, it does not execute the commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that manually by right click the database , then **Task > Restore > Database** , but if you want the script syntax.

**Below is the sample script in SQL Server 2012** , that script below is also generated by the wizard, there is option to generate the script on the wizard, you go to **Task > Restore > Database**, when the wizard appears, there is **script** button at the upper left part of the restoration wizard. (see image below)

[image]

```
USE [master]

RESTORE DATABASE DatabaseName1 FROM  DISK = 'C:\DATABASE\sample1.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'CRM' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DatabaseName1.MDF',  
MOVE N'CRM_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DatabaseName1.LDF',  
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

RESTORE DATABASE DatabaseName2 FROM  DISK = 'C:\DATABASE\sample2.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'CRM' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DatabaseName2.MDF',  
MOVE N'CRM_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DatabaseName2.LDF',  
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

GO
```

NOTE: Create first the database on the server, like it is blank database before the restoration. So in my sample script above, the database **DatabaseName1** and **DatabaseName2** is already existing in database.